# Periodic RDS Postgresql Replication Delays

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, amazon-cloudwatch, rds

I have been observing that my PostgreSQL read replica shows periodic delay for replication lags. The lag seems to build to up to 30-40 minutes and then automatically goes down to 0. There is a correlation with `CPU Utilization` but it's nowhere close to CPU limit.

- Read traffic comes from a reporting software called DOMO. DOMO periodically copies a large chunk of data & full tables into its warehouse.

Here's AWS Cloudwatch graph. The red line shows `Replication Lag` in seconds. The blue line shows the CPU load.

**Lag vs CPU**
[image: Periodic replication lag]

**Lag vs Network Out**[image]

**Lag vs Read IOPS**
[image]

**Lag vs Write IOPS**
[image]

Cloud: `Amazon RDS`

Instance Size: `db.m3.2xlarge`

PostgresSQL version: `9.3`

Postgres Settings:

Shared Buffers (Set by RDS) = 7.3 GB (956978 * 8KB)

**Updates**

- Tried setting `Shared Buffers` to 1GB (didn't help)

**Updates June, 5 2017**

- I created a branch new replica for my database and pointed the reporting software (DOMO) at it. Things in the new instance look stable for now. The old replica which has no read traffic now is stable as well. Beginning to suspect some type of AWS config issue or something to do what remaining artifacts in the database (vacuum?).

Answer (score 1):

RDS read replica lag metric isn't updated when there's nothing to replicate. If master database has no changes to replicate, then replica would only be updated on time-forced so called checkpoint - periodic sync of data from write ahead log to the tables.

This would cause the graph to look like above. To see the real graph data you'd have to generate some traffic on the master, for example update some special sequence every minute or even every second - depending how much resolution you need.

Also WAL-generation log of master and network utilization on replica graphs would be interesting - the alternative explanation would be that there are too much traffic (IO or network) for replica to handle and it can only catch-up when traffic stops.

Comment: I have verified that happens when there are lots more writes happening in the master. Attached network out graph. We attached this replica to a data warehouse tool called DOMO which periodically copies entire tables into its data store.

Comment: I've also checked that replay_location on the slave is much behind the master. 
WARNING: Stream: MASTER:7543524458904 Replay:7543440487376 :: REPLAY 83971528bytes BEHIND (00:22:38.922488seconds)